# Conditioning xpath on presence of sibling , lxml

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

Here is a sample of an xml:

```
<w:p>
   <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
      <w:b/>
   <w:t> There was a rich girl </w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
      <w:bCs/>
   <w:t> Nananananan </w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
      <w:b/>
      <w:bCs/>
   <w:t>If I had all the money in the world </w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
```

I want the text `"There was a rich girl Nanananan"` to be extracted but **not** `"If i had all the money.."` 
 I need to extract text corresponding to either `<w:b>` or `<w:bCs>` tags , but if both appear together , I need to skip the extraction.

In other words , extract text only if `w:bCs` is present or `w:b`.

What I've done is:

```
text2=" "
w = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'    
for r in p.xpath('.//w:t',namespaces={'w': w}):  
    if r.xpath('..//w:b|..//w:bCs[@w:val="0"]',namespaces={'w': w}):  
       text2 += r.text
```

This just checks whether w:b or w:bCs is present(and matches even if both are present). How could I add a condition for exclusivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'(..//w:b|..//w:bCs[@w:val="0"])[count(./..//w:b|./../w:bCs[@w:val="0"])=1]'`

So `count(./..//w:b|./../w:bCs[@w:val="0"])=1` will be `false` if there is more then 1 node in result,
and `[false]` will make main sequence to return nothing.

EDIT: First of all, that xml is really broken. Where is the closing tags for `w:rPr`'s ? Second, there is no attributes `w:val` in `w:bCs` tags `[@w:val="0"]`.
Still it is possible to achieve what you want:

```
for r in p.xpath('.//w:t[./ancestor::w:r[count(.//w:b | .//w:bCs)=1]]',namespaces={'w': w}):
    text2 += r.text
```

EDIT 2: Working loop with additional condition of `val="0"` and broken xml:

```
for r in p.xpath('.//w:t[./ancestor::w:r[(.//w:b or .//w:bCs[@w:val="0"]) and count(.//w:b|.//w:bCs)=1]]',namespaces={'w': w}):
     text2 += r.text
```

Comment: Hi , i've edited my question a bit. Could you take a look at that please.. The above code doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Thanks this works.. Can't this expression be used as the first one above??  I want to extract either w:b or w:bCs[@w:val="0"] and not extract if w:b and w:bCs(irrespective of val) occur together. I modified ur first expression as : '(..//w:b|..//w:bCs[@w:val="0"][count(./..//w:b|./../w:bCs)=1])' 
but it doesn't work.. Why??

Comment: It doesn't work because: 1. You misplaced closing parentheses, proper placing is as follows `(..//w:b|..//w:bCs[@w:val="0"])[count(./..//w:b|./../w:bCs)=1]`, so last condition applies on the result inside parentheses. 2. Provided xml is broken, in proper xml all tags should have closing tag, so in this xml `.//w:t/..` won't be `w:r`. So again here is working example: `(./ancestor::w:r//w:b|./ancestor::w:r//w:bCs[@w:val="0"])[count(./ancestor::w:r//w:b|./ancestor::w:r/w:bCs)=1]` and this is rather ugly.

Comment: how could i possibly use "or" statement for multiple expressions in count?

Comment: >>how could i possibly use "or" statement for multiple expressions in count? If you mean using '|' (pipe) in there, then pipe is not 'or' it is rather 'union', so it is just adds results from left and right side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65126/discussion-between-swordy-and-oleksii-matiiasevych).